# Should I begin building our Intranet using SP2016 now?

Tags: intranet

I've been asked to use SharePoint 2016 when it is released in August 2015 to begin a proof of concept for our company Intranet. I don't agree with this because it is not a stable product.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working with SharePoint 2013, especially taking into account the release dates for 2016. See [Roadmap](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/05/07/sharepoint-2016-roadmap.aspx). This project will generate a lower risk.

If your client understands the implications of working with a beta and unstable product, and only want to do a proof of concept, 2016 may be an option. But most do not understand these implications with which is generally not recommended.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you get the opportunity to **play** with the latest and greatest tools, and someone else is picking up the bill, you do not say no.